# Listing out parent then children

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a database structure for Categories as `id, name, parent_id`.

A user can input a category and if it doesn't have a parent, the `parent_id` field will be set to 0.

My view is a basic loop shown here:

```
  <% @categories.each do |category| %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle('one', 'two') %>">
      <td>

        <%= indent(depth(category.id)) %> 
        <%= best_in_place category, :name %>

        <%= link_to(image_tag('/images/delete.png', :class => 'delete'), "categories/delete/#{category.id}")%>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
```

The `indent(depth(category.id))` function is just a way to get the depth of the child category and add that many -'s for visual purposes.  http://d.pr/Ss8e

My problem is that the children aren't being listed under their respective parent.  I'm not sure how to go about this, any advice? (group_by or another loop maybe?)

**EDIT:** 
Sorry for not being clear.  The db structure I have is like this:

```
CATEGORIES
   id, name, parent_id, user_id
ITEMS
   id, name, category_id
```

I am looking to show the categories like this:

```
Parent1
  Child1
  Child2
Parent2
  Child1
```

Currently, the loop lists the items based on when they were created, it does not group them by parent_id like I'd like

Comment: do you have methods on your category `parent` and `children` ? if not, start there and create those

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the methods I have for Categories inside the controller is `@categories = @user.categories`

Comment: You still haven't told me what a parent is. Is it another category? such that a category can be associated as a child of another category?

Comment: Sorry, so I'm creating a parent/child category relationship where every category can have 1 parent and/or 1 child. (visual: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/nestedsets/nestedsets1.gif)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you should have:

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :parents, lambda {where("parent_ID IS NOT NULL")}
  scope: for_parent, lambda{|parent| where(:parent_id => parent.id)}

  def children
    Category.for_parent(self)
  end
end
```

Then in your controller:

```
@categories = Category.parents.all
```

And in your view

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= category.name %></td>
  </tr>
  <% category.children.each do |child| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= child.name %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried running that and got `Illegal instruction` in terminal and it quit the server instance

Comment: I update a typo in the category#children loop and the for_parent lambda. If that was the problem, easily fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With a parent_id, category BELONGS_TO parent, and parent has_many :categories

```
<% @parents.each do |parent| %>
  <h1><%= parent.name %></h1>
  <% parent.categories.each do |category| %>
    <!-- Your stuff here -->
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Does this enable me to create unlimited child categories?

Comment: I don't believe I understand... Do you have the has_many and belongs_to relationships set up in your models?

Comment: I have 1 Category table, 1 Items table and 1 User table.  Category belongs to User, Category has many items

Comment: so is User the parent? is parent_id a record of the user id? or is that something else?

Comment: Or does a category have other categories? If so, that changes the game and you weren't very clear about that

Comment: I can't see that, also, this is getting extensive. Please provide an alternate form of communication if you'd still like help